# ItemContainerStyle for Treeview using Class with List of SubClasses

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

My ObservableCollection is from Type FUClass. In this Class is a List of a FUSubClass. The ListView Itemsource is bound to the ObservableCollection FUList.

My TreeView shows the GroupName and a have one TreeViewItem with the ItemName.

The Problem is that only 1 TreeViewItem with all Items from the FUSubClassList is displayed but i want to have for every Item one TreeViewItem.
Dont know how to achieve that in the ItemContainerStyle.

**XAML ItemContainerStyle:**

```
<Style PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <TreeView Width="1248" MinHeight="50">
                        <TreeViewItem>
                            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding GroupName}" RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding FUSubClassList}">
                                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ItemName}" RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**C#**

```
    public class FUClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string groupName;
        public string GroupName
        {
            get { return this.groupName; }
            set
            {
                if (this.groupName != value)
                {
                    this.groupName = value;

                    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupName));
                }
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<FUSubClass> FUSubClassList = new ObservableCollection<FUSubClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<FUSubClass> FUSubClassList
        {
            get { return FUSubClassList; }
            set { FUSubClassList = value; }
        }

        public class FUSubClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {   
            private string itemName;
            public string ItemName
            {
                get { return this.itemName; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.itemName != value)
                    {
                        this.itemName = value;

                        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemName));
                    }
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FUClass> FUList = new ObservableCollection<FUClass>();
```

**UI**

[image: **UI**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `ItemContainerStyle` and define data templates for your data types, e.g.:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FUList}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FUClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding FUSubClassList}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FUSubClass}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the first thing I would do is to make a base class that the parent/child class can inherit from. I called it `FUBase` but here's what it looks like:

```cs
public abstract class FUBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _name, value);
        }
    }

    protected FUBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName));

        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, the parent class, which I called `FUGroup`, and the actual item class, called `FUItem` look like this:

```cs
public class FUGroup : FUBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<FUBase> Items { get; set; } = new ();

    public FUGroup(string name) : base(name)
    {

    }
}

public class FUItem : FUBase
{
    public FUItem(string name) : base(name)
    {

    }
}
```

Notice how the `FUGroup` class has an `ObservableCollection<FUBase>`? That lets you include either `FUGroup` or `FUItem` objects within each `FUGroup`. In the test app I made this was how I stored the top-level `ObservableCollection<FUBase>` (which I called `Items` in the `MainWindowViewModel`).

```cs
public ObservableCollection<FUBase> Items { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Items = new ()
    {
        new FUGroup("Group 1")
        {
            Items = new ()
            {
                new FUGroup("Group 1-2")
                {
                    Items = new ()
                    {
                        new FUItem("Item 1"),
                        new FUItem("Item 2"),
                        new FUItem("Item 3")
                    }
                },
                new FUItem("Item 4")
            }
        },
        new FUGroup("Group 2")
        {
            Items = new ()
            {
                new FUItem("Item 5")
            }
        }
    };
}
```

After that, the last thing you need is the DataTemplates. I just put them in the `TreeView`'s resources, but you could throw them in a `ResourceDictionary` or whatever parent `FrameworkElement`.

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:FUGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:FUItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The result:

[image: TreeView Result]